# Else statement confusion

Tags: vba, excel

```
If trigger = "Reconcile" Then
    If InStr(XXlist, checkmi) > 0 Then
          If checkmi = "XX1000" Then
            a = a + 1
            Call XX1000Check(location, a, checkmi)
          End If
          If checkmi = "XX1001" Then
            Call XX1001Check(location, checkmi)
          End If
          Else: Call SenseCheck(location, location2, location7, checkmi)
    End If
End If
```

I want my code to check if `Checkmi` is equal to one of the hardcoded codes(XX1000, XX1001) and to then call the appropriate VBA code. If however, there is no specific VBA module for that specific code, I want it to call the generic `SenseCheck`. Currently it executes `SenseChec`k if the initial condition `If InStr(XXlist, checkmi) > 0` is wrong, which is not what I want. And I am not entirely sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a good spot for a SELECT...CASE Syntax

```
      SELECT CASE checkmi 
         CASE "XX1000" 
               a = a + 1
               Call XX1000Check(location, a, checkmi)
         CASE "XX1001" 
               Call XX1001Check(location, checkmi)
         CASE ELSE
               SenseCheck(location, location2, location7, checkmi)
      END SELECT
```

Comment: Yes, that makes everything much cleaner. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You already terminated the `If` statement by `End If` below:

```
If checkmi = "XX1001" Then
    Call XX1001Check(location, checkmi)
End If '<~~ termination point
```

And you have an open `If` statement where you placed your `Else` statement.

```
If InStr(XXlist, checkmi) > 0 Then
      If checkmi = "XX1000" Then
        a = a + 1
        Call XX1000Check(location, a, checkmi)
      End If
      If checkmi = "XX1001" Then
        Call XX1001Check(location, checkmi)
      End If '<~~ termination point as pointed above
      Else: Call SenseCheck(location, location2, location7, checkmi)
End If '<~~ termination point
```

So the `Else` statement will be associated to the top most *non-terminated* `If` statement.
 And that is your very first `If` statement `If InStr(XXlist, checkmi) > 0 Then`.

**Edit1:**
To correct your code, include `Else` statement before terminating the entire `If` statement and also incorporate using `ElseIf` although if you have more conditions, using `Select Case` is desirable.

```
If InStr(XXlist, checkmi) > 0 Then
    If checkmi = "XX1000" Then
        a = a + 1
        Call XX1000Check(location, a, checkmi)
    ElseIf checkmi = "XX1001" Then '<~~ incorporate ElseIf statement
        Call XX1001Check(location, checkmi)
    Else '<~~ transfer the Else statement here
        Call SenseCheck(location, location2, location7, checkmi)
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

expanding on given answers, just to add that you may consider enhancing your code and improving its maintenance by adopting the same sub for both "XX1000" and "XX1001" `checkmi` values

this by means of "optional" parameters that a Sub/Function can have with the only requirement they must be kept as the last ones in their *signature*

for instance:

```
Sub XX100XCheck(checkmi As String, location As Long, Optional a As Variant)
```

would require the first two parameters to be passed and leaving the third one as optional. and by declaring this latter of `Variant` type you can check whether it has actually been passed or not:

```
Sub XX100XCheck(checkmi As String, location As Long, Optional a As Variant)

    If Not IsMissing(a) Then 'if "optional" 'a' parameter has actually been passed
        ' here place the code to process "optional" 'a' parameter
    End If

    '... rest of your code to handle "fixed" parameters

End Sub
```

so that your question code would be:

```
Select Case checkmi
    Case "XX1000"
        a = a + 1
        XX100XCheck checkmi, location, a ' call XX100Check sub passing all kind of parameters ("fixed" and "optional")

    Case "XX1001"
        XX100XCheck checkmi, location ' call the same sub as above, but now you're not passing it the "optional" a parameter

    Case Else
        SenseCheck(location, location2, location7, checkmi)
End Select
```

where you can use (and maintain) one sub only (i.e. `XX100XCheck()`) instead of two (i.e. `XX1000Check()` and `XX1001Check()`)

of course this is may not be taken as a *mandatory* coding pattern, since it may get at odds with another "good practice" one which calls for plain and simple routines as opposite to "all-in-one " ones

so it's a matter of balance (as always) and my proposal went out of a guessing from your code that the two `XX...Check()` subs would have minimal variations between them